# Segmentation fault on vsprintf using macros in C

Tags: c, macros

I create a simple logger library in C.I have three files

My example file:

- example.c

Library files:

- loglib.h
- loglib.c

My main logger function is called `logme`. I defined different macros as wrappers to indicate different log levels:

eg

- WARN
- ERROR
- etc..

In example.c I call the macros:

```
int int_arg = 55;
WARN(1, "Warn message with level 1");
WARN(1, "Warn message with level %d", int_arg);
```

The `WARN` macro is defined in `loglib.h`:

```
#define WARN(LEVEL, ...) \
    logme(LEVEL, 8, " <%s:%d> inside %s() -- "__VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);
```

And lastly here is the `logme` function:

```
void slog(int level, int flag, const char *msg, ...)
{
    char string[10000];
    bzero(string, sizeof(string));
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msg);
    vsprintf(string, msg, args);
    va_end(args);

    // .. do other things
}
```

When I run the example file this is what I get:

> inside main() -- Warn message with level 1
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I get segmentation fault when I call `WARN` with formated strings.

The segmentation fault appears in `vsprintf(string, msg, args);`

Is it something wrong with my macro?

Here is the make file of my lib:

```
CFLAGS = -g -O2 -Wall -lpthread
LIB = -lrt
OBJS = loglib.o

LIBINSTALL = /usr/local/lib
HEADINSTALL = /usr/local/include

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< $(LIB)

libslog.a: $(OBJS)
    $(AR) rcs liblog.a $(OBJS)
    @echo [-] Syncing static library
    sync

install:
    @test -d $(LIBINSTALL) || mkdir $(LIBINSTALL)
    @test -d $(HEADINSTALL) || mkdir $(HEADINSTALL)
    @install -m 0664 liblog.a $(LIBINSTALL)/
    @install -m 0664 loglib.h $(HEADINSTALL)/
    @echo [-] Done

loglib.o: loglib.h

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) liblog.a $(OBJS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution:

```
/* 
 * SOURCE_THROW_LOCATION macro returns string which 
 * points to the file, as well as, the corresponding line 
 * of the caller function.
 */
#define LVL1(x) #x
#define LVL2(x) LVL1(x)
#define SOURCE_THROW_LOCATION "<"__FILE__":"LVL2(__LINE__)"> -- "

#define WARN(LEVEL, ...) \
    logme(LEVEL, FWARN, SOURCE_THROW_LOCATION __VA_ARGS__);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can't work because you attempt string concatenation of `__VA_ARGS__` here:

```
#define WARN(LEVEL, ...) \
logme(LEVEL, 8, " <%s:%d> inside %s() -- "__VA_ARGS__, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__);
```

This messes up your sequence of parameters: `__FILE__` will not go with the `<%s`, etc. You must redefine your `WARN()` macro so that `__VA_ARGS__` is last. You'll have to write a proper variadic function if you want to prepend all that information. Note that `__func__` is not a string literal, it references the appropriate string.

Comment: please can you show me how to do it? I couldn't figure it out, and the documentations I found does not provide such detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering is incorrect when it hits the logme function.
You can do something like the following.

```
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void logme(int level, int flag, const char *msg_preamble, const char* file, int line, const char* function, const char* msg, ... ) 
{
    char buffer1[10000];
    bzero(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1));
    sprintf(buffer1, msg_preamble, file, line, function);

    char buffer2[10000];
    bzero(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msg);
    vsprintf(buffer2, msg, args);
    va_end(args);

    strcat(buffer1, buffer2);
    printf("%s\n", buffer1);
}

#define WARN(LEVEL, ...)                    \
  logme(LEVEL, 8, " <%s:%d> inside %s() -- ", __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, __VA_ARGS__);

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
   int int_arg = 55;
   WARN(1, "Warn message with level 1");
   WARN(1, "Warn message with level %d", int_arg);
}
```

Comment: nice solution but there are macros that just print strings and do not show the file-line. In your case I have to pass file-line to `logme` every time. What if I have a macro, let's say `INFO` that prints only formated text?

Comment: Then add #define INFO(LEVEL, ...)                    \
  logme(LEVEL, 8, "", "", 0, "", __VA_ARGS__);  The control is in the format string in the "level" macro :)

Comment: @ George. did that resolve the problem? any other issues? thanks

Comment: Ok great. If you feel that I contributed please approve my solution. This will help me and help others focus on unresolved questions. I am new here. I am still learning the ropes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The argument order is incorrect, hence the `%s` format does not correspond to the actual argument provided and the program invokes undefined behavior.

Here is a corrected version of the `WARN` macro:

```
#define WARN(LEVEL, ...) \
    logme(LEVEL, 8, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, __VA_ARGS__);
```

And the corresponding `logme` function, using `vsnprintf()` instead of `vsprintf()` to avoid potential buffer overflows:

```
void slog(int level, int flag, const char *filename, in lineno,
          const char *funcname, const char *msg, ...) {
    char string[10000];
    int prefix;
    va_list args;

    // check level, flag..
    ...

    // format the message if needed
    prefix = snprintf(string, sizeof string, " <%s:%d> inside %s() -- ",
                      filename, lineno, funcname); 

    va_start(args, msg);
    vsnprintf(string + prefix, sizeof(string) - prefix, msg, args);
    va_end(args);

    // do other things
    ...
}
```

Comment: nice code but what happens if we just want to pass a simple string? I get compile error `error: expected expression before ‘)’ token`

Comment: @GeorgeGkas: this case is tricky... I changed the answer with a different approach.  I had to change the API for the `logme` function.

Comment: It's a very good answer indeed. I just didn't accept it cause I found a better approach without chnaging the function prototype. Of course, I don't allow `__func__` variable but this is not a problem.